# check if textbox has changed since button press

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, textbox

I have a text box with a query the the user can load and change or leave alone. I have a test database that the user sends this to with a Development Test button. The results are displayed in another forms text box in XML.

Is there a way to check if the user changed anything in the text box since the development button was pushed? I have another button called production where, if the results returned to the user are correct the user can save this query to a production database.

What I want to prevent is a user loading a correctly worded query, test it, the results are good, and then the user changes something, either on accident or on purpose where this query will no longer work, and submitting it to production. At which point there will be errors and things will have to be found and changed. I would like a little message box that comes up and says: "The text box has been changed since you tested it are you sure you want to submit this to production". Now they can still submit it but at least they are warned..

Comment: What kind of textbox? Winforms? WPF? ASP?

Comment: Can you not just save the query to a local variable when the results are returned from dev, then use that for production? e.g. `button.Enabled = lastQuery == textbox.Text`

Comment: Or put the button which uploads to production on the message which indicates that the query is valid.

Comment: If javascript accessible, you can bind on("change") and set a hidden field.  If it's winforms same may hold true with an event.  Otherwise, just store the hash of their contents on the way up, and re-hash/compare when they resubmit.

Comment: Set a bool to false|true and then attach an event handle for Text.Changed and if Text.Changed occurs flag the bit, and then disable saving it to database until it has been validated. Validate on successful return from Test database. It also seems like a bad design to allow people to develop test queries and then if they don't fail, saving them to Production. Nothing should go into Production without knowledgeable eyes looking at it first.

Comment: thanks alykins I took your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Presume at some point a button is pushed or some action happens.

1) When you load the box, you could hold the original value in a variable
2) When the action occurs, you could re-query the same query and make another round-trip to retrieve the original value
3) Then compare the original value with current

```
  if (textBox.Text == myOriginalValue)
  {
  }
  else
  {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event, and update your field then.

```
textbox.TextChanged += (sender, e) => { textValue = textbox.Text; };
```

Answer (score 0):

set a dirty flag in a Tag property and check it.

```
//Set 1 in the Tag property after loading data
private void LoadData()
{
    textBox1.Text = myValue;
    textBox1.Tag = 0;
}

//Set 0 in the Tag property on TextChange
private void textBox1_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).Tag = 1;
}

//Check if Tag != 0 then do your stuff.
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Tag != null && Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Tag) != 0)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("The text box has been changed since you tested it are you sure you want to submit this to production", "Value Has Changed");
    }
}
```